# jquery .onsubmit doesnt trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, submit

I blocked since some hours with a problem.
I want to trigger the .submit event and test before validate. But when i debug if i put a breakpoint on the $("#btnSub").submit It detects but just go to end without executing my code.

```
//on submit
//_________________________________________________________
$('#btnSubs').submit(function(e) {
    //Check if form is already shown
    if ($('#collapseState').val() === "true") {
        //Check content before send
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        var valid = (chckPseudo() === true) && (chckMail() === true) && (chckMail2() === true) && (chckPWD() === true); //define a valid flag

        if (valid) {
                 //disable the btn to avoid multiple connections
                $(this).button('loading');
               //submit the form
               return true;
        } else {
            if (chckPseudo())
                formValidate("grpPseudo", "correct");
            else
                formValidate("grpPseudo", "incorrect");

            if (chckMail())
                formValidate("grpMail", "correct");
            else
                formValidate("grpMail", "incorrect");
            if (chckMail2())
                formValidate("grpMail2", "correct");
            else
                formValidate("grpMail2", "incorrect");


            if (chckPWD())
                formValidate("grpPSW", "correct");
            else
                formValidate("grpPSW", "incorrect");  
            //dont submit
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

    }
    //show form
    else {
        $('#collapseSubscribe').collapse('show');
        $('#collapseState').val("true");
        // don't submit the form
        e.preventDefault(); 
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you could give me some clues it will be very very kind(exasperation)
(The code works i know because before I used in .click event and No I havent forget to put a form and button type submit)
Thank you!!

The html in case

```
<div id="logIndex">
    <h3>Toute question a une réponse</h3>
    <form method="post" id="reg" action=""> 
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseSubscribe">

            <div class="form-group" id="grpPseudo">
                <label class="control-label sr-only" for="psdo">Pseudo</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pseudo :" id="psdo" /><br>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span id="psdo" class="sr-only"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="grpMail">  
                <label class="control-label sr-only" for="mail">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email :" id="mail"/><br>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span id="Email" class="sr-only"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="grpMail2">  
                <label class="control-label sr-only" for="mail2">Confirmer email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirmez email :" id="mail2"/><br>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span id="Email2" class="sr-only"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="grpPSW">
                <label class="control-label sr-only" for="psw">Mot de Passe</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe :" id="psw"/>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span id="pwd" class="sr-only"></span>
            </div>

            <p id="conditions">En vous cliquant sur S'inscrire,vous acceptez nos conditions et reconnaissez que vous avez lu notre politique d'utilisation des données</p>      
        </div>
        <button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-loading-text="<img src='./ressources/loading.GIF' alt='chargement...'>" type="submit" id="btnSubs"  >
        S'inscrire
    </button>
    </form>



    ou <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Se Connecter</a>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Se Connecter</h4>
            </div>
           <!-- <form id="login_form" method="post" action=""> -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pseudo ou Email :"/><br>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de Passe :"/>
            </div>
            <!--</form>-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Se Connecter</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!-- collapse State -->
<input type="hidden" value="false" id="collapseState">
<!-- My CSS   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./MyStyle.css">-->

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="./scripts/renders.js"></script>
<script src="./valider.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/Observer.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    })
</script>

<script>javascript:(function() {
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.onload = function() {
            bootlint.showLintReportForCurrentDocument([]);
        };
        s.src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootlint/latest/bootlint.min.js";
        document.body.appendChild(s)
    })();</script>
```

Comment: There is not "jquery .onsubmit"...

Comment: Please put `alert("somethig")` at the beginning of submit function for testing.

Comment: Is `$('#btnSubs')` your submit button?

Comment: There is not much we can say without you posting the html markup, I am afraid...

Comment: @hamed already Done ^^  dfsq Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, the problem appears because you bound `onsubmit` event to submit button, however there is no such event buttons have.

onsubmit event is an event of the HTMLFormElement, so you need to select your form and listen to its event:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    // your code
});
```

Comment: Yea, but the submit event is detected it stop on breakpoint $().submit it just that the next step is on the end of the event and not my code. TK

Comment: But yes your true ive due with form an works thanks .Now i have to see why we couldnt use selectors ^^.  Thank your really much. Maybe because the submit event is on form element and button got any submit event.